# What to pass into my RepositoryFactory instance function

Tags: c#, repository, entity, repository-pattern

I've been learning MVC for about 2 weeks now, moving over from PHP, and am bit of a novice. I've been following tutorials for creating a generic repository pattern, namely this one in particular https://sharpcodeblog.wordpress.com/tag/c/. Where I'm confused is how to call the GetRepositoryInstance() method.

So far what I have is

RepositoryFactory:

```
public sealed class RepositoryFactory
{
    private static RepositoryFactory _instance;
    private static readonly object _padlock = new object();

    public static RepositoryFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_padlock)
            {
                return _instance ?? (_instance = new RepositoryFactory());
            }
        }
    }

    private RepositoryFactory()
    {
    }

    public static IRepository<T> GetRepositoryInstance<T, TRepository>()
       where TRepository : IRepository<T>, new() where T : System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject
    {
        return new TRepository();
    }
}
```

and where I'm calling it:

```
public AccountUserMembershipProvider(IRepository<AccountUser> iRepository) : base()
    {
        _repository = iRepository ?? RepositoryFactory.GetRepositoryInstance<AccountUser, Repository<AccountUser>> ();
    }
```

However the error I get is "The type 'Portfolio.Models.AccountUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'RepositoryFactory.GetRepositoryInstance()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Portfolio.Models.AccountUser' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'.

This seems like the only logical data to pass to the method but apparently not. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The error means that it requires `AccountUser` is derived from `EntityObject` (per your declaration of `GetRepositoryInstance`). Other than that, the syntax is fine.

Comment: To be precise it's the following part that limits you: `where T : System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject` to only this type. So either you should use a class which derives from EntityObject or alter this part

Comment: As a side point, I see no reason in defining the repository factory class as singleton since all it does is creating new instances of repositories.

Comment: How would I derive from the entityobject? @CharlesMager

Comment: also should i be using DbContext instead?

Comment: AccountUser : EntityObject i assume

Comment: I'm not convinced the linked blog post is terribly helpful, especially given it dates from 2011. I would expect most current guidance to suggest using EF Code First, which wouldn't involve having entities derive from `EntityObject`. And you're more likely to see dependency injection used than using a singleton factory.

Comment: I'm also not sold on hiding EF behind a generic repository when EF already implements the repository pattern itself.  But that's [a whole other argument](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/220126)...

Comment: Yeah I have seen this argument, but I'm new to all this so am trying all things out and seeing for myself. All sites linked to entityobjects seem to be fairly dated so I think that's probably a sign to not go down that route of inheriting from it. I'm going to try another method for the RepositoryFactory instead, any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed the method to this:

```
public static IRepository<T> GetRepositoryInstance<T, TRepository>(params object[] args)
    where TRepository : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
    {
        return (TRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TRepository), args);
    }
```

calling it like this:

```
RepositoryFactory.GetRepositoryInstance<AccountUser, Repository<AccountUser>> ()
```

Works as needed